# Nested table isn't updated in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I am trying to update a nested form. The client table is updated successfully but the location table isn't update. Instead of its creating a new location. Do you guys have any solution ? I've already spend one day on it.

My models:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :allow_destroy => true, :update_only => true
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end

Selectcom::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :clients
end
```

My Controller:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_client, only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @clients = Client.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @client = Client.new
  end

  def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)

    if @client.save
      flash[:success] = "Client added successfully"
      redirect_to clients_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @client.update(only_client_params)
      flash[:success] = "Job updated successfully"
      redirect_to clients_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def set_client
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])  
  end

  def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(
      :name,
      :phone,
      :fax,
      :url,
      :address,
      :city,
      locations_attributes: [
        :site,
        :fax,
        :phone,
        :url,
        :address,
        :_destroy
      ]
    )
  end
end
```

This is the client's edit.html.erb form

```
<%= form_for(@client, class: 'form-horizontal') do |f| %>
  <%= render(partial: 'client_field', locals: {f: f}) %>

  <%= f.fields_for :locations do |l| %>
    <%= l.hidden_field :client_id, value: @client.id %>
    <%= l.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= l.text_field :site, class: 'form-control' %>

  <% end %>
 <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn lg-button" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you have two issues here. One in your Model and other in your Controller permitted params. Let's dig into them:

**1) Model**

The `update_only` option is **ignored** when used with collection association (it is your case), as said in Rails documentation:

> For a **one-to-one** association, this option allows you to specify how
>   nested attributes are to be used when an associated record already
>   exists.  In general, an existing record may either be updated with the
>   new set of attribute values or be replaced by a wholly new record
>   containing those values.
>
> **By default the :update_only option is false** and the nested attributes are used to update the existing record only if they include
>   the record's :id value. Otherwise a new record will be instantiated
>   and used to replace the existing one.
>
> However if the :update_only option is true, the nested attributes are
>   used to update the record's attributes always, regardless of whether
>   the :id is present. **The option is ignored for collection
>   associations.**

So, the first step would be removing the `update_only` option of your **Client** class, because it will be ignored since you have a `has_many` association (collection association) with **locations**:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**2) Controller**

You have to permit the `:id` key for the `:locations_attributes` array. Since your `update_only` option in the model was ignored, Rails needs the param to tell that it is a record that exists and it's being updated rather than created.

You can solve your issue using the following in your **client_params** method (note the addition of the `id` key in your `:locations_attributes` key):

```
def client_params
  params.require(:client).permit(
    :name,
    :phone,
    :fax,
    :url,
    :address,
    :city,
    locations_attributes: [
      :id, # Should be present; otherwise, Rails thinks that is a new record
      :site,
      :fax,
      :phone,
      :url,
      :address,
      :_destroy
    ]
  )
end
```

I hope it helps !!

Comment: Oh my God, I got it buddy. It's really working. I've already spend about 10-12 hours on it. And you've rescued me. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're very welcome ! It would be nice though if you upvoted and accepted the answer. This way other users could refer to it if they pass to the same trouble you had =P

Comment: Did it work? If it did you can also accept the answer by clicking the check mark beside it. It is a nice step to take =P